# Laravel 4 query builder - with complicated left joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

I'm new to Laravel 4.

I have this query:

```
SELECT a.id, active, name, email, img_location, IFNULL(b.Total, 0) AS LeadTotal, IFNULL(c.Total, 0) AS InventoryTotal
FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) as Total
   FROM lead_user
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS b ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) as Total
   FROM user_inventory
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS c ON a.id = c.user_id
WHERE a.is_deleted = 0
```

How can I convert it to Laravel query builder? I'm confused on how to use the Laravel join query builder with this type of query.

**Answer!!**

Will all the help of petkostas on laravel forum. We got the answer.

```
$users = DB::table('users AS a')
->select(array('a.*', DB::raw('IFNULL(b.Total, 0) AS LeadTotal'), DB::raw('IFNULL(c.Total, 0) AS InventoryTotal')  ) )
->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as Total FROM lead_user GROUP BY user_id) AS b'), function( $query ){
    $query->on( 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id' );
})
->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as Total FROM user_inventory WHERE is_deleted = 0 GROUP BY user_id) AS c'), function( $query ){
    $query->on( 'a.id', '=', 'c.user_id' );
})
->where('a.is_deleted', '=', 0)
->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should work:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->select( array('users.*', DB::raw('COUNT(lead_user.user_id) as LeadTotal'), DB::raw('COUNT(user_inventory.user_id) as InventoryTotal') ) )
    ->leftJoin('lead_user', 'users.id', '=', 'lead_user.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('user_inventory', 'users.id', '=', 'user_inventory.user_id')
    ->where('users.is_deleted', '=', 0)
    ->get();
```

Comment: The output is not correct. It doubles the counting when it founds a record between lead_user and user_inventory tables.

Answer (score 2):

This type of query is very hard to build with query builder. However, you can use `DB::select`

**if you have nothing to bind, you can use following:**

```
DB::select("SELECT a.id, active, name, email, img_location, IFNULL(b.Total, 0) AS LeadTotal, IFNULL(c.Total, 0) AS InventoryTotal
FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) as Total
   FROM lead_user
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS b ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) as Total
   FROM user_inventory
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS c ON a.id = c.user_id
WHERE a.is_deleted = 0");
```

if need to bind parameter with the query:

```
$deleted = 0;

DB::select("SELECT a.id, active, name, email, img_location, IFNULL(b.Total, 0) AS LeadTotal, IFNULL(c.Total, 0) AS InventoryTotal
FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) as Total
   FROM lead_user
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS b ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) as Total
   FROM user_inventory
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS c ON a.id = c.user_id
WHERE a.is_deleted = ?", [$deleted]);
```

Comment: I can used this, but I think there is a way to manage it using query builder join. Thanks anyway. This will be my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, use of ORM relations is a better way to join the tables.

please refer the link: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships