# how list model sorted by number of DOWN-VOTES cast to related model - laravel, eloquent

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, left-join

Thanks to help from @LukasGeiter I improved on my quotations and books database. 
After 4th edit I simplified my problem to this:

I am now able to list certain type of writers and sort the list by their importance and 'likes' & 'dislikes' assigned to a given autor

This is the code which produces my collection:

```
$targetted = Capacitytype::find($capacity);  // this selects Sci-Fi writers only from among all writers

$rank_entities_by_capacity = Entity::join('entity_capacitytypes', function($q) use ($capacity){
     $q->on('entity_capacitytypes.entity_id', '=', 'entities.id');
     $q->where('entity_capacitytypes.capacitytype_id','=', $capacity);
 })->leftJoin('user_attitudes', function($q) {
                $q->on('user_attitudes.entity_id', '=', 'entities.id');
                $q->where('item_type', '=', 'entity');
            })

->selectRaw('entities.*, SUM(user_attitudes.importance) AS importance'
             , SUM(user_attitudes.attitude) AS attitude'
)
->groupBy('entities.id')
            ->orderBy('importance', 'desc')
            ->take(6)
            ->get();
```

What I need:

1) I want to sort the list by number of UPVOTES assigned to each listed author by particular user

The code contributed by lucas does the job:

```
 'SUM(IF(user_id = ' . Auth::user()->id . ', user_attitudes.attitude, 0)) AS karma_current_user'
```

Now I want another sorting method:

Each author has certain number of quotes  said and books published.
User can UPVOTE and DOWNVOTE these creations

in the table user_attitudes it looks like this:

```
> id  |  item_id  |  item_type  | entity_id  | importance | attitude (VOTES) | creator_id


> 1   |  51         | entity    | 51         | -1               |100

> 2   |  32         | book      | 51         | -1               |100

> 3   |  33         | book      | 51         | -1               |100
```

In plain English: 
- The entity 51 received a downvote for life-time achievement from user #100 (lukas provided the code already)

- also, two books (#32 and #33) written by the same Entity (#51) received DOWN-VOTES for their content.

**Thing to do:** 
I need to list the Entities (Sci-Fi writers in this case) and sort the listing by these DOWN-VOTES assigned to books they authored. IN the above example the author is scored "-2".

- Note: the column entity_id duplicates info on related entity - i added it to avoid joining extra pivot table with info who about authorship.

### A good real-life example:

To translate my want into StackOverflow model, I now can assign likes to people who are helping me (lukas gets a +1 UP-VOTE in my table user_attitudes.attitude). I can also list all users who received likes from me. This is done. 
Now I want to see  a ranking of users sorted by the number of answers they contributed to my own questions. Lukas gets the 1st place on the list with c. 6 answers... etc.

### Possible solution:

Possibly I only need to add an **extra IF clause** in this line

```
 'SUM(IF(user_id = ' . Auth::user()->id . ', user_attitudes.attitude, 0)) AS karma_for_books'
```

conditions to add:

```
IF user_attitudes.item_type = book 
IF user_attitudes.entity_id = (entity)....
IF attitude = '-1' // counting downwotes only
```

I dont know the syntax rules for this task.

Do we need an extra leftJoin?
Aftrer two changes of the DB structure I am confused.
This things might help: 
[Laravel 4 query builder - with complicated left joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773790/laravel-4-query-builder-with-complicated-left-joins)

[Laravel Eloquent and Multiple Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842977/laravel-eloquent-and-multiple-joins)

but it is beyond me...

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Thx

Comment: I have found this solution: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/10/05/how-to-count-values-with-mysql-queries/ but still the problem with user-related queries stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `IF` inside inside `SUM()` should work. Try this:

```
$selects = array(
    // your existing selects
    'SUM(IF(user_attitudes.attitude = -1, 1, 0)) AS dislikes',
    'SUM(IF(user_attitudes.attitude = 1, 1, 0)) AS likes',
    'SUM(IF(user_id = ' . Auth::user()->id . ', user_attitudes.attitude, 0)) AS karma_current_user'
);
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand you right. Does it work and now you want to know why?

Comment: your suggestion to get karma_current_user works great. But please take a look at the bottom of my original post, after edits.
What I need is to count not the VOTES for an Entity, but firstly, mismatches between user_attitudes and entity_attitudes toward a question; secondly, user's VOTES for the entity's attitudes.

Comment: ok, I have spit my user_attitudes table. Now, the new table contains user's attitudes toward entity's attitudes. I still have no Idea to build the query... The dillea is: should I keep user's attitudes toward entities in the old table, or move them to the new?

Comment: Now we're at the point we were last time. It's about the db design. I can't answer you because I don't know exactly how your data is structured and linked together. And I don't want to know because I don't have the time to read me in. Whatsoever it's totally ok to do two queries.

Comment: Ok, I managed to do this - I can count the disliked books!
I have just problem with printing it in my vew. Please take a look!

Comment: Try this in your raw select `SUM(IF(attitude = -1,1,0)) as disliked books`. Regarding the view problem I have no idea how you get the `misdeedsagainstUser` but you could try this: `$o->misdeedsagainstUser[0]->misdeeds`

Comment: I resolved the issue with printing only DOWN_VOTES. But after adding the "[0]->misdeeds" i get this error: Undefined offset: 0

 If there are no disliked books to count, I see only quare brackets: []

Comment: You could do something like this `@if($attitude = $o->booksdislikedbyUser->first()) {{ $attitude->dislikedbooks }} @endif`

Answer (score 0):

1) If the scores will never change from -1, 0, or 1, then you can just do a count:

```
// Positive:
$positive = UserAttitude::where('importance', '>', 0)->count();

// Negative:
$negative = -1 * UserAttitude::where('importance', '<', 0)->count();
```

I'm assuming a Laravel model called UserAttitude which represents that table. Shouldn't be hard to adapt to a more custom query if you need it.

2) Not quite sure what you're looking for here, as adding another where clause for this specific query shouldn't change the totals.

Comment: I need to rethink it. Check out my re-edited question. Most likely I will use your suggestion for a much simpler widget I would build later.
Thank you